# Is creating MPI_Groups at runtime possible?

Tags: c++, mpi

I am trying to create MPI groups based on the number *k* so in each group we have equal number of processes and the last group takes whatever remains as well. So for example if we have 5 processes and *k = 2*, we are going to have group_1 = {0,1} and group_2 = {2,3,4}
The problem is when I start to run my code, it seems that what ever I generate the last overwrites all the previous groups which I have created. I don't know if it's a C++ error or an MPI one. Here is the code:

```
        MPI_Group world_group;
        MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD , &world_group);
    
        int num_groups = k;
        int num_members = numtasks / num_groups;
        int rm_members = numtasks % num_groups;
    
        MPI_Group* groups = new MPI_Group[num_groups]();//Creating MPI groups dynamically
        
        int group_ranks_size[num_groups] = {};
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < ( num_groups - 1) ; ++i)
            group_ranks_size[i] = num_members;
        group_ranks_size[num_groups - 1] = num_members + rm_members;
        
        int** group_ranks = new int*[num_groups];
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < num_groups ; ++i){
            group_ranks[i] = new int[group_ranks_size[i]]();
        }
    
        int id_counter = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < num_groups ; ++i){
            for(size_t j = 0 ; j < group_ranks_size[i] ; ++j){
                group_ranks[i][j] = id_counter;
                id_counter++;
            }
        }
    
        //Printing to check
        if(rank == 0){
            for(size_t i = 0 ; i < k ; ++i)
                cout<<group_ranks_size[i]<<endl;
    
            for(size_t i = 0 ; i < num_groups ; ++i){
                for(size_t j = 0 ; j < group_ranks_size[i] ; ++j){
                    cout<<group_ranks[i][j]<<",";
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }   
        //***
        
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < num_groups ; ++i){
    
            MPI_Group_incl(world_group , group_ranks_size[i] , group_ranks[i] , (groups+i));
    
        }
    
        // Get my rank in the small group
        int my_small_group_rank;
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < num_groups ; ++i){
            MPI_Group_rank(groups[i], &my_small_group_rank);
        }
    
    
        if(my_small_group_rank != MPI_UNDEFINED)
        {
            printf("I am process %d in world group and %d in small group.\n", rank, my_small_group_rank);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("I am process %d in world group but I am not part of the small group.\n", rank);
        }
```

Comment: An other (and) simpler approach is to `MPI_Comm_split()` and get the group from the created communicator.

Comment: Yes. I have done so and it works but the problem is that I want use MPI_Comm_create_group() ultimately because it's not a collective command whereas MPI_Comm_split() is. So I need to declare my groups using new.

Comment: Each process calls `MPI_Group_rank(groups[0])` instead of using the group it is in. Since a given MPI task is part of only one group, you should not have an array of groups anyway.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I have deleted this part. The error still remains but this time, it happens for groups[0] because we come out of the for loop with groups[1]. The question is I have correctly included the ranks for groups[0] and groups[1] and I expect only processes rank 0 and 1 belong to groups[0] and 2,3,4 belong to groups[1]. I don't understand why they overwrite on each other when using MPI_Group_rank(groups[i], &my_small_group_rank);

Comment: That’s because you `MPI_Group_rank(groups[i], &my_small_group_rank);` in a `for` loop do you keep overwriting `my_small_group_rank`